# How to enforce the maximum and minimum number of characters allowed in a string

Tags: c#, string, properties

I want to limit my string, so that you have to put a minimum of 3 chars and a max of 10 chars in. Is this possible in the following code below?

main.cs:

```
class Program
{   
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Something hello = new Something();
        string myname;

        Something test = new Something();
        myname = Console.ReadLine();
        test.Name = myname;
    }
}
```

class with properties:

```
class Okay : IYes
{
    private string thename;

    public string Name
    {
        get {return thename;}
        set {thename = value;} //what to put here???
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "limit". You can always ask again *after* input; but there is no UI validation in a console app.

Comment: BradleyDotNet is right, there is no default validation. There are certain design patterns that make validation easy to add, but I'm guessing this homework and design patterns might be too confusing at this point

Comment: Thanks alot, this helped, I defined it with a limit now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Okay : IYes
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Name");
            if (value.Length < 3 || value.Length > 10) 
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Name");
            name = value;
        }
    }
}
```

You can also truncate the string if it's too long, rather than throwing an exception by just taking (up to) the first 10 characters:

```
class Okay : IYes
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Name");
            if (value.Length < 3) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Name");
            name = string.Join("", value.Take(10));
        }
    }
}

private static void GenericTester()
{
    Okay ok = new Okay {Name = "thisIsLongerThan10Characters"};
    Console.WriteLine(ok.Name);
}

// Output:
// thisIsLong
```

Comment: Added null check. Note that this means once the name is set, there is no way to 'clear' it!

Answer (score 2):

The `setter` is probably not the best place to check.  You should make the check at the point of input:

```
  string myname = "";
  while (myname.Length<3 || myname.Length >10)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name (between 3 and 10 characters");
    myname = Console.ReadLine();
  }
  test.Name = myname;
```

Obviously you can take some steps to make this more user friendly: maybe a different message after the first failure, some way of getting out of the loop, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
public string Naam
        {
            get { return thename; }
            set
            {
                if (value.Length >= 3 && value.Length <= 10)
                    thename = value;
                else
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            } 
        }
```